# What sort of address is 0x0000000140001000?

Tags: memory, portable-executable, ida

I'm using IDA Pro and right at the top of file is a field labelled Imagebase. Would this address be a absolute virtual address or relative virtual address or something else ?

```
0x0000000140001000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the image base (in windows PE files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655287/what-is-the-image-base-in-windows-pe-files)

Comment: @DavidGrayson thank you for the comment but that article does not exactly answer my question. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer I was looking for as written in the following article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646344/what-is-difference-between-image-base-address-virtual-address-and-relative-virt) It says "In PE file format, Image base address is used for binary virtual address itself." Meaning it is not considered a absolute virtual address.

Comment: Image base address is the address at where the PE file locates. It is an absolute address in the virtual address space of its process. Hence, it is not correct that *"it is not considered a absolute virtual address."*.